# Global callback function in ionic mobile app

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am integrating a third party js library in my app. The js library has a callback function, to which a global function can be assigned. I have defined a global function in index.html.

```
<body>
  <script>
  function js_callback(response){
    var js_event = Event('js_event',response)
    window.dispatchEvent(js_event);
  }
  </script>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

When I try to call this function from console I am getting a console error with a message **'TypeError: Constructor requires 'new' operator'**. The js library takes a global function name as a param, so this global function should be invoked just by directly calling it. like

```
js_callback('test');
```

I searched for a long time and couldn't find any solution on my own. Can someone suggest a fix for this?

I tested this on - iPhone 6 simulator (debugged in safari browser).
env info:

```
   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.5.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here but is it this line:

```
var js_event = Event('js_event',response)
```

Which maybe should be:

```
var js_event = new Event('js_event',response);
```